# Debugging TCP/IP Port Exhaustion in an Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, tcp, ravendb, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting a TCP/IP Port exhaustion error on a web application deployed to Azure App Services. The issue is related to a RavenDB connection session eating up the ports. I think I have a fix and should be good but I feel outclassed as I really wasn't able to do much for debugging in the deployed environment.

In debugging the issue I tried to access netstat but I get access is denied message and can't seem to get around it. Any thoughts?

On a tangent: How are ports allocated in an Azure webapp? Options put forward (as outlined in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx) there are to reduce socket connection timeout value or increase the upper range of ports dynamically allocated to client TCP/IP socket connections. However, I don't think this is possible in Azure Web Apps.

Comment: Hi @JoanieBrar, we are experiencing similar issues. I am starting an investigation now, and will return to this post with possible findings - but before I start, can you tell, what you fix was? White-box reduction of Raven-calls, extend port-range, or?

Comment: Honestly mate we are still experiencing some challenges on this front in our web application. We were able to eliminate the issue for our current traffic load by pulling out Signal R (by its nature it was holding on to sessions longer), being prudent as to when sessions were being opened, and disciplined in closing down sessions when no longer needed. However, it is still an issue in our backlog to revisit, as with an increased load we expect to see the port exhaustion to re-emerge. Sorry I couldn't be of any greater assistance or provide any deeper insights.

Comment: We are having similar issues debugging port exhaustion in Azure. We have 20+ apps on one pricing plan, and it seems that at present the 'plan' is also a VM, and all apps on that plan simultaneously lose tcp connectivity. There is presently no way via portal or powershell of identifying which app is the culprit and so far MSFT tech support are not able to tell which app is the culprit   either,

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but we are now experiencing the same issue. We also use Signalr, but websockets are supposed to be unlimited on azure. Does signalR somehow also consume regular connections?

We just use build in web api and entityframework, so it's not even like we control connections at all, and yet they pile up, sometimes gradually over time, sometimes relatively suddenly, until we reach the limit and whole VM goes down.

Answer (score 1):

This could possibly be solved by updating your Ravendb instance! Read more here:
https://ayende.com/blog/173057/production-postmorterm-houston-we-have-a-problem.

From changelog, [release 3.0.30100](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/start/whats-new):

> Fixed UDP port leak in licensing component

also this, from 3.0.30115:

> **[Major]** [Prefetching] Fixed memory leak that could lead into slowness
>   of the server under heavy load impacting indexing and replication
>   mechanisms

And some useful knowledge on Azure services and availability of ports: 
http://www.freekpaans.nl/2015/08/starving-outgoing-connections-on-windows-azure-web-sites/

In short, the issues goes for `async` calls where the UDP reply packet for whatever reason is dropped/lost. Before the issue was solved, this would mean an `async` call that keeps listening for the response until e.g. a crash or iisreset.

We are rolling out the upgrade to try to fix our instance of the same issue within the next 24 hours, but I thought I would reply right away, so you might be able to test too if this is indeed your problem.

I will get back to this post to confirm that the issue will go away - only way to know for sure is to update Ravendb and wait and see for a week or two.

Comment: Thanks so much Frederik! Will review and look to test out a solution on our end as well. Good luck on your testing!